# Algorithm floating like figure with border

Tags: captions, minipage, algorithmicx

This is my document (LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require{lala}
    \Statex
    \Function{yolo}{x}
    \State $x \leftarrow 0$
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
  \captionof{algorithm}{yolo bla bla bla}
\end{minipage}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

And that's how it looks:
[image]

I want it to stay that way but put a border (same width as the text) around the pseudo-code/algorithm (caption not included, of course!) and there should be more space around the whole thing like with figures.

For any help: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a KOMA-script class, that means package `tocbasic`
is loaded and ready to use. The interface is a simple key-value
list, you just have to define a type (*algorithm*), names
(*Algorithm* and *List of Algorithms*) and decide if it should be
a floating environment (`float`) or not (in that case you have to
do things a bit special).

Since your new toc is handled by KOMA you get all the fancy
features. You can use the listof-command natively and it will get
a `toc` entry if the option is set and so on.

Package `mdframed` provides a simple command to surround a given
environment with a frame. Instructions on how to customize it are
given in the documentation.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{a4wide}%JB: Do you really need this?
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\surroundwithmdframed{algorithmic}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=algorithm,%
    float,%
    name=Algorithm,%JB: <- this isn't even necessary
    listname=List of Algorithms]
    {loa}

%JB: Just in case we want to switch the language to german ;-)
\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\listalgorithmname}{Liste der Algorithmen}
\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\algorithmname}{Algorithmus}

\KOMAoption{listof}{totoc}
\begin{document}
%\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\tableofcontents
\listofalgorithms
\chapter{let's have a look}
\Blindtext
\begin{algorithm}
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require{lala}
    \Statex
    \Function{yolo}{x}
    \State $x \leftarrow 0$
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{yolo bla bla bla}
\end{algorithm}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```